# The Page Numbers Position is not getting fixed in centre

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am using `fancyhdr` package but the page number are shifting right on odd number pages and shifted left on even.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\usepackage{geometry}

% Set the page margins
\geometry{
    paperwidth=8in,
    paperheight=11in,
    left=0.75in,
    right=0.75in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    headheight=0in,
    headsep=0in,
    footskip=0in,
    includeheadfoot,
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

Image:

[image: Display]

I want them to be at centre

If Some one want to access full code
Please See The following link, you may edit it too
https://www.overleaf.com/3887911651rqbpgvqknhfr

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to post only code, which will compile. Thank you

Comment: Actuall, The Code is large i cant provide the full file. if some one want i can give him overleaf file access where he can see exactly what is causing the error. @MS-SPO

Comment: @PiyushBaweja that's not how this site works, questions and answers are here to benefit all, now and in the future, not just the asker. Edit your code down into a small example we can compile and edit it into your question please otherwise this is impossible to help with

Comment: you can always show a small complete document that demonstrates your issue

Comment: Actually I am not able to compile it in a small code i have given overleaf which is example of error. there are nested files how i can give all codes here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the overleaf i have given is a small document of what error i am getting

Comment: See I have edited it, you  must take a look

Comment: @PiyushBaweja, you can replace your real text e.g. by the lipsum package, see my solution below. If so, please make sure it also shows non-centered page numbers.

Comment: @PiyushBaweja your issue seems to be caused by loading `geometry` twice with two different options - can you clarify which page geometry you want? The first one (`\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
`) or the one set with `\geometry`?

Comment: the one set with \geometry

Comment: @MS-SPO I did it, check the edited question

Comment: set up fancyhdr after you set the page size

Comment: It worked thanks @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @PiyushBaweja, the purpose of the lipsum package is to have more compact code. Rather than typing "Lorem ispum ..." you just call `\lipsum[1-15]` to show 15 paragraphs of said text.

Comment: Ok Thanks @MS-SPO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

note you get multiple warnings

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 14.49998pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}.
(fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:

(fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-14.49998pt}.


Package fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (0.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 14.49998pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\footskip}{14.49998pt}.
```

But mostly you need to set up the page head *after* you set the page size

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}


% Set the page margins
%\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=8in,
    paperheight=11in,
    left=0.75in,
    right=0.75in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    headheight=0in,
    headsep=0in,
    footskip=0in,
    includeheadfoot,
}

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{15pt}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, what you are doing. (Please don't answer to this solution, but rather EDIT and refine your question.) This way page numbers **are** already centerd.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: See  i have edited my question